# kendo ui scheduler: Creating Complex Event Templates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, telerik, kendo-ui

WE are trying to looking into the flexibilities of Kendo UI with Razor.

We are using MVC4 razor view JQXwidgets and kendo scheduler

On the Custom Event Template i want to add some JQX controls like dropdownlist, text boxes, calender controls etc.

Need help as in how i can use the defined resources and bind them to a JQX control

This is My Scheduler:

@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler()
    .Name("AScheduler")
    .Date(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13))
    .StartTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 7, 00, 00))
    .Height(600)

```
.Editable(editable =>
{
    editable.TemplateId("UpdateTemplate");
})   
.Views(views =>
{
    views.DayView();
    views.WeekView();
    views.MonthView(monthView => monthView.Selected(true));
})
.Timezone("Etc/UTC")
.Resources(resource =>
{
    resource.Add(m => m.ReasonId)
        .Title("Reason")
                       .DataTextField("Text")
                       .BindTo(new[] { 
                     new { Text = "John", Value = 1, Color = "#f8a398" } ,
                     new { Text = "Bob", Value = 2, Color = "#51a0ed" } ,
                     new { Text = "Dell", Value = 3, Color = "#56ca85" } 
                 });
    resource.Add(m => m.managerId)
        .Title("Owner")
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .DataColorField("Color")
        .BindTo(new[] { 
            new { Text = "John", Value = 1, Color = "#f8a398" } ,
                     new { Text = "Bob", Value = 2, Color = "#51a0ed" } ,
                     new { Text = "Dell", Value = 3, Color = "#56ca85" } 
                 });
}))
```

This is my Update Template:

"

```
#  $("\\#templateReasonId").jqxDropDownList({ source: DATA, selectedIndex: 0 }); # 
    // I want the DATA used above, to come from resources
   <div id="templateReasonId">Reason Type: </div>
    <div>Hours: </div>
    <div>Charge: </div>
    <div>Comment:</div>
    <div>Client</div>
```

"

Answer (score 0):

Kendo code library has an example where you can create the template in another view. See example [here](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-editor).